# How to convert analog signal (0-10v) to pressure unit ?(Arduino,pressure gauge TPG362)

Tags: arduino

I have an input pressure signal (0-10V from TPG362), so I have changed my Arduino to (0-10v). I want to read the pressure value to my computer, but I have no idea how to convert voltage (0-10) to pressure unit.

My question is: how to convert the voltage (0-10) to the pressure unit? Is this code is correct to print pressure to my computer?

Thank you.

```cpp
const byte pressureInput = (A0)

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  input_pressure_value=analogRead(pressureInput)
  Serial.println(input_pressure_value)
  delay(1000)
}
```

Comment: `so I have changed my Arduino to (0-10v)` what do you mean by that?

Comment: By adding circuit  (with op-amp or another way) output of Arduino become (0-10V)

Comment: Read the datasheet for your sensor, that's the first step.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: how to convert the voltage (0-10) to the pressure
> unit?

TPG362 is a dual gauge controller. So assuming it outputs the measured value as 0-10V the manual will give you some conversion formula.
If it is a linear relation you'll get some factor you multiply the voltage reading with.

> By adding circuit (with op-amp or another way) output of Arduino
> become (0-10V)

Why would you want to output 0-10V when reading a sensor?